# Firefox policy set "page blocked" text

Tags: firefox

Friends,
i have restricted access to web pages with a policy.json file with WebsiteFilter block/exception.
How can I change the text shown when surfing to blocked pages? The default message has no option to go back to the homepage, which basically locks the browser forever when in kiosk mode (no navigation buttons).

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

To customize the blocked page message, locate the policy.json or relevant configuration file, create a custom error page with a homepage link, update the configuration to point to your custom error page, test your changes, and seek assistance if needed.

Comment: "update the configuration to point to your custom error page" - what would the policy.json entry for that be?